# Who is Goddess Nirrti?

Tags: scripture

[Manusmriti Chapter 11:](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm)

> 119. But a student who has broken his vow shall offer at night on a
>        crossway to Nirriti a one-eyed ass, according to the rule of the
>        Pakayagnas.

It says if a twice born men, who is a Brahmachari, intentionally emitted his semen, he should offer a one eyed ass to Nirriti. Now, my questions are:

- Who is that goddess Nirriti?
- Which scripture describes about her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So the God of Fire has got his burning power and is residing in the
>   bellies of the Devas, the Asuras, men and all other beings and
>   penetrating their bellies, is satisfying all. Yama, the King of
>   Dharma, by Thy appointment, is the Lord of the southern quarters, is
>   presiding over the Pitris and being the witness of all the actions of
>   the Jivâs, is awarding duly to them the fruits thereof.
>
> Nairrita, the Lord of the Raksasas, the witness of all the actions of
>   all the beings, by Thy commandment, is the destroyer of all the
>   obstacles of the devotees that take refuge unto thee, though he is a
>   Yaksa. The Varuna Deva, by Thy order, has become duly the Lord of the
>   waters, and the Regent of the Loka (Dikpâla). The Vâyu, the Life of
>   all, the carrier of the smell, has become by Thy order Lokâpâla and
>   the Guru of the universe. Kuvera, obedient to Thy order, has become
>   the Lord of the Yaksas and the Kinnaras and is holding a respectful
>   position like other Lokapâlas
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 8.2**

She is the consort of Nairrita and the guardian of the south-west direction, which is also known as the Nairitika Kona.

In the above passage, the names of some the Dikpalas/Lokapalas are found. Like Agni (who guards south east), Yama (south), Varuna (west), Vayu (north west), Kubera (north) etc..

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_directions) the list of Astha Dikpalas are as follows:

> Kubera (North)
>   Yama (South)
>   Indra (East)
>   Varuṇa (West)
>   Īśāna (Northeast)
>   Agni (Southeast)
>   Vayu (Northwest)
>   Nirṛti (Southwest)

There is also the concept of 10 Dikpalas in which Brahma and Vishnu are also included.