# Are the eight directions and their deities associated with eight orifices of body?

Tags: gods, vastu-shastra

Are the eight directions and their deities associated with eight orifices of body? If so, can someone please list the deities associated with each of the orifices, and their associated organs?

Comment: Actually there are 9 openings in body with 10th being crown of head. But eight directions is reflection of same 8 directions in body. Vaastu shastra was based on deities inside our body in certain directions was written and same outside. But what are 8 directions is secret because it is known through only Yoga sadhana!

Comment: Oh, thought so, thanks for the info. I've realised that lakshmi resides In kidney, spleen, along with varuna in pancreas, spleen, as well as in traditional Chinese medicine, kidney is activated in evening till sunset, same time as lakshmi. If I know correctly Ashwini kumaras are in two nostrils, indra might be crown of the head.

Comment: I can mention one because its in Yogic texts. Agni is near navel. Thats why you see Brahma being born of Vishnu Navel. I can give you clue. See pictures and histories behind birth of Brahma, and histories of Vishnu and his symbols. You'll get all the answers from there! Symbols of Vishnu has more tattva and secrets! So try to understand it!

Comment: Yes of course I do know that, that Agni is in navel, that's how he causes everything to digest. Vishnu is in entire digestive system, meanwhile Vishnu as Narayana is inside our subtle body, channels. Meanwhile brahma is in reproductive system, especially female. Meanwhile shiva is in male organs, entire nervous system.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32192), we know which deity rules over which direction.

> Kubera (North) Yama (South) Indra (East) Varuṇa (West) Īśāna
>   (Northeast) Agni (Southeast) Vayu (Northwest) Nirṛti (Southwest)

Now, in our head we have 7 (8 if we count the Brahmarandhra) orifices viz - mouth, 2 eyes, 2 nostrils, 2 ears.

And, the organs of procreation and excretion are the 8th and 9th orifice. That means we have in all 9 orifices in our body (leaving aside the Brahmrandhra).

Aitareyopanishad (which is linked to the Rig Veda) gives associations of these senses with deities as follows:

> I-i-4: He deliberated with regard to Him (i.e. Virat of the human
>   form). As He (i.e. Virat) was being deliberated on, His (i.e. Virat'’)
>   mouth parted, just as an egg does. From the mouth emerged speech; from
>   speech came Fire. The nostrils parted; from the nostrils came out the
>   sense of smell; from the sense of smell came Vayu (Air). The two eyes
>   parted; from the eyes emerged the sense of sight; from the sense of
>   sight came the Sun. The two ears parted; from the ears came the sense
>   of hearing; from the sense of hearing came the Directions. The skin
>   emerged; from the skin came out hair (i.e. the sense of touch
>   associated with hair); from the sense of touch came the Herbs and
>   Trees. The heart took shape;
>
> from the heart issued the internal organ (mind); from the internal
>   organ came the Moon. The navel parted; from the navel came out the
>   organ of ejection; from the organ of ejection issued Death. The seat
>   of the procreative organ parted; from that came the procreative organ;
>   from the procreative organ came out Water.

Thus we have the following associations:

> Mouth -- Agni
>  Eyes -- Sun
>  Nostrils -- Vayu
>  Ears -- Directions
>  Genitals
>   -- Water 
>  Anus -- Yama.

Now, you can yourself see if the presiding deities are the same or not. By the way, some other Upanishad associates Prajapati with the genitals instead of Water.

Comment: Ears are associated with directions and therefore ears should be related to deities of all the directions!

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case but that seems absurd .. @commonman