# Deities associated with various organs in Human body?

Tags: scripture, gods, body

I need a scripture reference for Deities associated with various organs in Human body.

[This site](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/how-are-deities-associated-with-various-organs-in-human-body.html#1) gives information about it. Is it real or made up by website author?

Is there any Verse which gives information about it?

Comment: Not made up by the author.

Comment: Any Scriptural reference?

Comment: Yes we have reference from Upanishads. I have already posted an answer. Need to find that.

Comment: For the time being I am able to find [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22379) .. If you check the Nyasa mantras given there, you will get the idea of which deity is associated with what organs of our body. Besides that we have ref. from Upanishad too. I am not able to find that answer currently.

Comment: Okay here is the other answer I was talking about: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34620. It has a ref. from one of the major Upanishads. The links between deities and organs are given there too.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for your Hardwork.